# How to parse a url using Javascript and Regular Expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I want to parse some urls's which have the following format :-

```
var url ="http://www.example.com/cooks/cooking-dress-wine/~no-order/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=bks%2C43p&mycracker=ch_vn_clothing_subcategory_Puma&ref=b41c8097-8efe-4acf-8919-0fa81bcb590a"
```

Its not necessary that the domain name and other parts would be same for all url's, they can vary i.e I am looking at a general solution.

Basically I want to strip off all the other things and get only the part:

```
/cooks/cooking-dress-wine/~no-order/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=bks%2C43p
```

I thought to parse this using JavaScript and Regular Expression

I am doing like this:

```
var mapObj = {"/^(http:\/\/)?.*?\//":"","(&mycracker.+)":"","(&ref.+)":""};
var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"),"gi");
url = url.replace(re, function(matched){
  return mapObj[matched];
});
```

But its returning this

```
http://www.example.com/cooks/cooking-dress-wine/~no-order/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=bks%2C43pundefined
```

Where am I not doing the correct thing? Or is there another approach with an even easier solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use :

```
/(?:https?:\/\/[^\/]*)(\/.*?)(?=\&mycracker)/
```

**Code :**

```
var s="http://www.example.com/cooks/cooking-dress-wine/~no-order/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=bks%2C43p&mycracker=ch_vn_clothing_subcategory_Puma&ref=b41c8097-8efe-4acf-8919-0fa81bcb590a";
var ss=/(?:https?:\/\/[^\/]*)(\/.*?)(?=\&mycracker)/;
console.log(s.match(ss)[1]);
```

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jY0nX5)**

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SujithPS/2JwG7/)**

**Explanation :**

[image: explanation]

Comment: What would be the solution if the word cook is not there ? I mean I constructed this url to just to give glimpse of the problem I am facing.

Comment: Yes this seems to be nice.

Comment: Yeah Jason, I also liked it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just map a split array?

You don't quite need to regex the URL, but you will have to run an if statement inside the loop to remove specific GET params from them. In this particular case (key word particular) you just have to substring till the `indexOf` "&mycracker"

```
var url ="http://www.example.com/cooks/cooking-dress-wine/~no-order/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=bks%2C43p&mycracker=ch_vn_clothing_subcategory_Puma&ref=b41c8097-8efe-4acf-8919-0fa81bcb590a" 
var x = url.split("/");
var y = [];
x.map(function(data,index) { if (index >= 3) y.push(data); });
var path = "/"+y.join("/");
path = path.substring(0,path.indexOf("&mycracker"));
```

Comment: But still I want to get rid of &mycracker=ch_vn_clothing_subcategory_Puma&ref=b41c8097-8efe-4acf-8919-0fa81bcb5‌​90a and I the url above is just an indicative url, same script I would Like to use in all scenarios

Comment: Updated to truncate the URL at the index of "&mycracker" and the URL matched your desired URL.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following code a little bit and you can retrieve any parameter:

```
var url = "http://www.example.com/cooks/cooking-dress-wine/~no-order/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=bks%2C43p&mycracker=ch_vn_clothing_subcategory_Puma&ref=b41c8097-8efe-4acf-8919-0fa81bcb590a"
var re = new RegExp(/http:\/\/[^?]+/);
var part1 = url.match(re);
var remain = url.replace(re, '');
//alert('Part1: ' + part1);
var rf = remain.split('&');
// alert('Part2: ' + rf);
var part2 = '';
for (var i = 0; i < rf.length; i++) 
    if (rf[i].match(/(p%5B%5D|sid)=/))
        part2 += rf[i] + '&';
part2 = part2.replace(/&$/, '');
//alert(part2)
url = part1 + part2;
alert(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url ="http://www.example.com/cooks/cooking-dress-wine/~no-order/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=bks%2C43p&mycracker=ch_vn_clothing_subcategory_Puma&ref=b41c8097-8efe-4acf-8919-0fa81bcb590a";
var newAddr = url.substr(22,url.length);
// newAddr == "/cooks/cooking-dress-wine/~no-order/pr?p%5B%5D=sort%3Dfeatured&sid=bks%2C43p&mycracker=ch_vn_clothing_subcategory_Puma&ref=b41c8097-8efe-4acf-8919-0fa81bcb590a"
```

`22` is where to start slicing up the string.

`url.length` is how much of it to include.

**This works as long as the domain name remains the same on the links.**

Comment: But still I want to get rid of &mycracker=ch_vn_clothing_subcategory_Puma&ref=b41c8097-8efe-4acf-8919-0fa81bcb590a

and I the url above is just an indicative url, same script I would Like to use in all scenarios.